# Vectorization using numpy.where()

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, where-clause, hstack

Given an array of objects:

```
a = numpy.array([[True,False],[True,True],[True,False,True]])
```

Expected output:

```
[[0],[0,1],[0,2]]
```

Is there a way to get this output using numpy.where()(may be with numpy.vstack() or numpy.hstack()) or some other numpy functionality that I am not aware of?

So far I've tried:

```
c = [numpy.hstack(numpy.where(a[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
```

This solves my purpose but I want to vectorize it using numpy functionalities!

PS : Don't want any loops!

Comment: You can't have a numpy boolean array like that. Only an array of objects

Comment: `a` has lists of different length; the expected ouput is also a mix of lists. (Look at `c` without the `hstack` - what is multidimensional about that?).

Comment: Even if I make the length of the lists( or objects) same ( say a = numpy.array([[True,False],[True,True]) and use c = (numpy.where(a)[1], I am getting c = [0,0,1] ( a flattened array). But what I want is to have c = [[0],[0,1]] (a 2d list/array) instead!  How to do the split in between? @hpaulj